# RGB JTextfields - changes colour even if other boxes are empty when 3 values are required

Tags: java, jtextfield, rgb

If anything is entered in the blue textfield (tblue) even when the others are empty, it changes the text to that colour, if a box is empty or contains letters, it should produce an error message. This error doesn't happen for the other boxes and it works as it's supposed to, even though it's the same code.

```
package FirstCE203Project;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class CE203_2016_Ex1 extends JFrame {

    JTextField tred, tgreen, tblue;
    JLabel message;                              //to reference later on
    JButton goButton, reset;


    public CE203_2016_Ex1() {

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();       //creates panels for the boxes that will hold the rgb values
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();

        tred = new JTextField("Red", 10);
        tgreen = new JTextField("Green", 10);             //creates boxes for rgb values
        tblue = new JTextField("Blue", 10);

        panel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());           //sets text to the centre of the panel

        panel1.add(tred);
        panel1.add(tgreen);                            //adding panels to frame
        panel1.add(tblue);


        add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH); //adding panels to frame              //location of panels on frame
        add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panel3, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        message = new JLabel("hello");  //text
        message.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));     //original text set to red

        JButton goButton = new JButton("Change"); //adds button to change colour
        JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");


        panel1.add(goButton);
        panel2.add(message);
        panel3.add(reset);                  //adding buttons to panels

        goButton.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler(this));
        reset.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler1(this));                    //creating action listener

    }


    class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        private CE203_2016_Ex1 theApp;

        public ButtonHandler(CE203_2016_Ex1 theApp) {
            this.theApp = theApp;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int a=0, b=0, c=0;

            try {
                a = Integer.parseInt(theApp.tred.getText());

                if (a < 0) {
                    a = 200;                                           //if statements for values above and below the targets set
                    tred.setText("200");
                }

                if (a > 255) {
                    a = 255;
                    tred.setText("255");
                }
                message.setText("CE203 Assignment submitted by: Steven Beresford - 1404398");
                message.setForeground(new Color(a, b, c)); //changes colour to desired input
            }

            catch(NumberFormatException ex) {

                message.setText("invalid input! please enter numbers only");  //text
                message.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));     //error message set to black
                tred.setText("");
            }

            try {
                b = Integer.parseInt(theApp.tgreen.getText());

                if (b < 0) {
                    b = 200;
                    tgreen.setText("200");
                }

                if (b > 255) {
                    b = 255;
                    tgreen.setText("255");
                }
                message.setText("CE203 Assignment submitted by: Steven Beresford - 1404398");
                message.setForeground(new Color(a, b, c)); //changes colour to desired input
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ey) {

                message.setText("invalid input! please enter numbers only");  //text
                message.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));     //original text set to red
                tgreen.setText("");

            }

            try {
                c = Integer.parseInt(theApp.tblue.getText());

                if (c < 0) {
                    c = 200;
                    tblue.setText("200");
                }

                if (c > 255) {
                    c = 255;
                    tblue.setText("255");
                }
                message.setText("CE203 Assignment submitted by: Steven Beresford - 1404398");
                message.setForeground(new Color(a, b, c)); //changes colour to desired input
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ez) {

                message.setText("invalid input! please enter numbers only");  //text
                message.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));     //original text set to red
                tblue.setText("");
            }

        }
    }


    class ButtonHandler1 implements ActionListener {

        private CE203_2016_Ex1 theApp;

        public ButtonHandler1(CE203_2016_Ex1 theApp) {
            this.theApp = theApp;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            message.setText("CE203 Assignment submitted by: Steven Beresford - 1404398");
            message.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));                 //resets message back to red
            tred.setText("Red");
            tgreen.setText("Green");
            tblue.setText("Blue");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame app = new CE203_2016_Ex1();
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.setSize(700, 700);
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually does what you want, but the text is then overridden immediately (and this is why you can't see the change).

Let's say that you enter an invalid value for green (`b`).

The message will be set to "invalid input ...".

```
try {
    b = Integer.parseInt(theApp.tgreen.getText());
    ...
} catch (NumberFormatException ey) {
    message.setText("invalid input! please enter numbers only");
    ...
}
```

but then you have a valid input for blue (`c`):

```
try {
    c = Integer.parseInt(theApp.tblue.getText());
    ...
    message.setText("CE203 Assignment submitted by: Steven Beresford - 1404398");
    ...
}
```

and this will override the "invalid input ..." value with "CE203 Assignment ...".

---

A possible solution:

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
        boolean isValidA = true, isValidB = true, isValidC = true;

        try {
            a = Integer.parseInt(theApp.tred.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            isValidA = false;
        }

        try {
            b = Integer.parseInt(theApp.tgreen.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            isValidB = false;
        }

        try {
            c = Integer.parseInt(theApp.tblue.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            isValidC = false;
        }

        if (!isValidA) {
            tred.setText("");
        } else {
            if (a < 0) {
                a = 200;
                tred.setText("200");
            } else if (a > 255) {
                a = 255;
                tred.setText("255");
            }
        }

        if (!isValidB) {
            tgreen.setText("");
        } else {
            if (b < 0) {
                b = 200;
                tgreen.setText("200");
            } else if (b > 255) {
                b = 255;
                tgreen.setText("255");
            }
        }

        if (!isValidC) {
            tblue.setText("");
        } else {
            if (c < 0) {
                c = 200;
                tblue.setText("200");
            } else if (c > 255) {
                c = 255;
                tblue.setText("255");
            }
        }
        if (isValidA && isValidB && isValidC) {
            message.setText("CE203 Assignment submitted by: Steven Beresford - 1404398");
            message.setForeground(new Color(a, b, c));
        } else {
            message.setText("invalid input! please enter numbers only");
            message.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        }

    }
```

Comment: so what do i need to change? I'm still confused by what you mean

Comment: I've just tried this, and it only works now for the first box? apparently the int a is redundant now too

Comment: yeah i can't get this to work mate, only the first box clears if its invalid now?

Comment: basically, if a string is entered, it should clear and any boxes with an integer should not be cleared. the code originally, if the first 2 boxes are empty, and an integer is entered in the 3rd box, it changes colour, it should only change colour when 3 values are entered

Comment: @sb33 , now I think that it's exactly what you want. Please check this new method.

Comment: yeah that works perfectly! cheers! i see what you've done and it makes sense!